# Why does this pointer show the last element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

Please explain to me how the `b` pointer shows the last element.

Every time, it prints out the last element, no matter how long the array is. If you use `*b` alone in `cout`, it shows a number out of array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    int *b =(int*) (&a+1);
    cout << *(b-1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is `sizeof(a)`?

Comment: BTW, this is also undefined behavior but I haven't seen a compiler that doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
&a+1
```

has the type `int ( * )[11]` and points to the memory after the last element of the array `a`.

In this declaration

```
int *b =(int*) (&a+1);
```

you interpreted the expression as having the pointer type `int *`  that points to after the last element of the array a. Instead you could write

```
int *b = a + 11;
```

So the expression

```
b - 1
```

points to the last element of the array `a`.

Thus you may imagine the expression `*( b - 1 )` the following way

```
*( a + 11 - 1 ) => *( a + 10 ) => a[10]
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [pointer arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Pointer_arithmetic) rules, incrementing/decrementing a pointer by `N` elements will adjust the value of the pointer by `N * sizeof(T)` bytes, where `T` is the dereferenced type of the pointer.

`&a` is a pointer to the array itself, which has a type of `int[11]`, so you have a pointer of type `int(*)[11]` to the beginning of the array.  Lets call this `A1` in the diagram below.

Adding +1 to that pointer will advance it by `sizeof(int[11])` (aka `sizeof(int)*11`) bytes, thus producing a new `int(*)[11]` pointer to the memory address immediately following the entire array.  Let's call this `A2` in the diagram.

You are then *type-casting* that new pointer, so now you have a pointer of type `int*` to the end of the array. This is the memory address you are assigning to your `int *b` pointer variable.  Lets call this `B1` in the diagram below.

Subtracting -1 from that pointer will reduce it by `sizeof(int)` bytes, thus producing a new `int*` pointer to the memory address of the last `int` element in the array.  Lets call this `B2` in the diagram below.

So, when you dereference `b` to print the `int` that it is pointing at, you are printing the value of the last `int` in the array.  If you don't decrement `b`, it is pointing past the end of the array, and you have *undefined behavior*.  You might just print out random garbage, or you might crash your app.  Anything could happen.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10  |  11  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
^                                                            ^      ^
|                                                            |      |
|_A1 --------------------------------------------------------|----->|_A2
                              +1                             |      |
                                                             |_B2 <-|_B1
                                                                -1
```

Comment: Actually, it is UB as is. Casting a pointer between a type which is an array, to the type of an element of the array is UB. However, this sort of thing is quite often done and `std::complex` even carves out an exception so that C functions can be called with a known structure.

Comment: @doug "*Casting a pointer between a type which is an array, to the type of an element of the array is UB.*" - how is it UB? By definition, for purposes of pointer arithmetic, a pointer can point at the beginning or the end of an object. So we obtain a valid pointer to the end of the array, casting that pointer to the element type isn't changing the address, only the pointer type. And now that casted pointer can point at the beginning or end of any element of the array, and as long as it is dereferenced only while within the bounds of the array, the behavior should be well-defined, I think

Comment: An array of T is a different type than a T. You can't cast a pointer from one type to another (with a few carve outs like signed unsigned) without UB. That said, it's not exactly uncommon for this to be done and as far as I know all compilers produce the expected code. Personally, I believe this shouldn't be UB but I don't write the standard.